# smbclent send message Windows User

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, lan, smb

I am trying to send a message to a Windows User from a Ubuntu User on the same LAN subnet. I can see the user's computer and PING IT from Ubuntu.

```
cat mymessage.txt | smbclient M BRIDGE2
```

Error:

```
Connect to BRIDGE2 failed. Error NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME.
```

How could this be? THe only difference is that the Windows computer in question is connected to a domain and the Ubuntu computer that is trying to send the message is NOT on a domian.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Its possible the problem is the domain, easy enough to confirm with a free virtual machine, but I doubt it considering Ubuntu being on a Windows domain is not common.  Have you found the conditions for the `NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME` error?

Comment: The Ubuntu Host is on a virtual machine

Comment: How is the network adapter set?

Comment: Attached to Bridge Adapter (ETHERNET) Promiscuous Mode Deny. Cable Connected (checked). Virtual Machine on same network as physical computer.

Comment: Did you do `smbclient M BRIDGE2` or `smbclient -M BRIDGE2`? Note the `-M` instead of just `M`. (ps. just added an [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/695155/bash-script-tells-me-when-new-computer-joins-lan-via-smbclient/698657#698657) to your other question with a script)